# Android: Application to manage files on SDcard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, delete-file, sd-card

I have a problem with understanding how to manage files at SDcard in the tablet.
I have my own application in Kotlin (in manifest.xml I have a permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) and I need to have a folder "SongBook" in the root of SDCard. In this folder will be stored audio files (mp3) and HTML files. I read files without problems, but I need to create and delete these files. Now I use a File.

```
var file = File(Path_to_file)
try { file.delete() } 
   catch (e: Exception) { println("exception: "+ e.toString()) }
```

To create a file and write data to it, I use FileWriter. As I wrote, my app has permissions, but the file isn't deleted (or isn't created a new file).

I know about Android 4.4 KitKat's idea that applications not have access to SDcard to write. Apps may use a 'providers folder' with all permissions. But this folder is deleted after uninstalling application - no way for me. Data stored in "SongBook" is my own (like photos or videos) and must stay stored on SDcard after application uninstall.
Please, I need help, is any correct way to do this (without rooting android device) and using a folder in the root of SDcard to read/write/delete/create files?
Thx for responses (and sorry for my English).

Comment: You cannot use the classic file approach to write on every place of a removable sd card. Instead use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose the micro sd card. After that you can do what you want with the card using methods of storage access framework.

Comment: I was talking about a removable -micro- sd card. Did you?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about a removable micro-SDcard too.
Thx for your answer. 
I must use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE only once time for application, or every time when I must write to file or delete file?

Comment: Only once if you take the persisted uri permissions.